# modify the name of the output folder

Tags: linux, shell-script

I'm trying to loop over different files and execute a program with them.

The multigeneblast generate a directory with .HTML files

The problem that I found is that every output should be saved in a new directory. If not I loose what I did in the previous iteration

I got an idea to add a counter(c) that will change the name of the output folder every time.
But when I do it after the first iteration there is no change in the number and the directory is overwritten by the next file.

on the right to the -out is the directory name that I'm trying to modify in every iteration.

Here is my code

```
 c=1
 for f in ./*.fasta
 do
 ./multigeneblast -in "${f}" -db betaproteobacteria.pal -minpercid 10 -distancekb 20 -out "${c}MGB_ycei" 
 c=$((c+1))
 done
```

excpected output

1MGB_ycei
2MGB_ycei
.
.
.
nMGB_ycei

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Hi, Nicolas. "It seems not to work"  is not very helpful to understand what is going on. Any error message or no new files at all? The program looks alright but we do not know what `multigeneblast` does.

Comment: Thank you @Quasímodo I edited the question. Hope is clearer now

Comment: Can you confirm the loop really runs multiple times by adding an `echo ${c}MGB_ycei` inside it?

Comment: There is a typo in what I wrote. it is  "${c}MGB_ycei" what I add. It runs multiple times

Comment: Put `echo` in front of the multigeneblast thing. When you run it, does the line look right?

Comment: It is still unclear what the issue is. I see no error in your shell code. Is it simply the fact that when you run the script multiple times, the _same_ output directory names are used?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
c=1
 for f in ./*.fasta
 do
 ./multigeneblast -in "${f}" -db betaproteobacteria.pal -minpercid 10 -distancekb 20 -out ${c}_"MGB_ycei" 
 c=$((c+1))
 done
```

Try the counter outside the quotes, followed by string within the quotes

The `out` argument take the iterator outside the quotes.

Underscore has nothing to do over here

`${c}."MGB_ycei"`

Even keeping a dot here will work.

It might also be due to coding utilized in `./multigeneblast`

I have faced similar problem in python scripts utilized for preparation of ligands and receptor for drug docking. Might also be because the script may be pythonish.

Comment: That work, create the amount of folders that I need

Comment: There is no real difference between this and the code in the question apart from an inserted underscore in the pathname used as output name.  What is the issue and how do you solve it here?

Comment: @Kusalananda It is strange acctually. For my understanding, which is vage, it could be maybe that it is taking it as a number rather than a string. But, I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: @Nicolas _In this particular case_, using `${c}` inside or outside the quotes should not matter. The added underscore is not magical in any way either.

Comment: I tottally agree with the underscore that does not change anything

Comment: @Nicolas the out argument seem to take the iterator variable outside the quotes. I have traditionally seen in my projects. Hence I suggested.

Comment: Please also let me know the reason for downvoting. So that i can improve.

Comment: @PraveenKumar-M I did like the answer. I cannot downvote nor upvote due to my reputation. But, for what I’ve seen people usually expect an explanation for why your code works or what the problem in the question was and how did you solve it.

Comment: Ok Sure. Just before sleeping last night, I typed the answer and slept. Missed out on explanation. Will definitely do it from now. Anyways i added in morning. @Nicolas